# Conditional Attribute Routing

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

When using attribute routing, is it possible to remove routes based on certain runtime condition - such as licensing?

Something like this:

```
[LicensedRoute("/api/whatever")]
```

where '/api/whatever' is only added to the route table if the application is licensed.

Obviously I can explicitly do the check in the action method or use an action filter to validate the requests but ultimately I prefer the route not to be available if the software is not licensed.

Comment: Probably custom authorization attribute is more relevant in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need Attribute Routing: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Is it RESTful? How you store the licensing info: is it user logins? tokens? key?

You could do it RESTful and force the client to pass a token every time via token-based authentication, for example: define several "licence" levels/types (eg. Free/Trial/Basic/Pro) and then in a persistent storage (table) map tokens (guids) to a licence type. 

Then using a custom attribute, mark each endpoint/controller/action with the minimum required licence type to be accessible (e.g. `[MinimumLicence("Basic")]`). And then create "routing tables" based on the licence required.

In this case you would deny access to routes rather than "remove" them.

Comment: So the short answer is No.